# Eloquent outside laravel change fetch mode to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent outside laravel,
and here's my code for initializing Eloquent,
but I wasn't able to change fetch mode to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,

```
    $capsule->addConnection([
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('Database_Host'),
        'database'  => env('Database_Name'),
        'username'  => env('Database_Username'),
        'password'  => env('Database_Password'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_persian_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ]);


    $capsule->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//    $capsule->getConnection()->getPdo()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//    $capsule->setAsGlobal();

    return $capsule->getConnection();
```

Comment: Why? You're using `Eloquent`, If you just want to use PDO, then use PDO. One is a database ORM, and the other is a way for developers to expose themselves to exploits through writing vulnerable code.

Comment: I know what Eloquent is and I want to use it, I want eloquent result to be associative array.

Comment: So call `->toArray()` on your queries

Comment: It returns array of std class objects,
I need associative array .

Comment: How much data is in a typical result?  Can you use transform?
$collection->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    return get_object_vars($item);
});

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this for every query or just one? For all try:

```
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('Database_Host'),
    'database'  => env('Database_Name'),
    'username'  => env('Database_Username'),
    'password'  => env('Database_Password'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_persian_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'fetch'     => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
]);
```

For a single query try:

```
$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Comment: I want all my queries to fetch assoc.
I have some complex queries.

Comment: Have you tried the above, adding a "fetch" parameter to the connection configuration? It shouldn't really make a difference as that is what setFetchMode does anyway, but it's worth a try.